# What is the differences between spark.table("TABLE A") and spark.read.("TABLE A")

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Question as the title,I am learning sparkSQL,but I can't get a good understanding of the difference between them. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference between `spark.table` & `spark.read.table` function.

Inside of `spark.read.table` is again calling `spark.table` function.

Check below code.

`spark.table` It is available inside `package org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession`

[SparkSession](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/cfecc2030d8b4774c1f4754fe81f57fbc61c9c75/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.scala#L579)

```
package org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

def table(tableName: String): DataFrame = {
  table(sessionState.sqlParser.parseTableIdentifier(tableName))
}
```

`spark.read.table` function is available in `package org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader` & It is again calling `spark.table` function.

[DataFrameReader](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/cfecc2030d8b4774c1f4754fe81f57fbc61c9c75/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L777)

```
package org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader

def table(tableName: String): DataFrame = {
   assertNoSpecifiedSchema("table")
   sparkSession.table(tableName)
}
```

Comment: This is always why spark confuses me, many apis can do similar or even same things, making me lost and don't know why what's the difference and why